# How to override a is_member() in-built function in databricks

Tags: python, sql, databricks, aws-databricks

I am trying to override is_member() in-built function in such a way that, it always return true. How to do it in databricks using sql or python?

What is the library that needs to be imported to use is_member() in-built function in databricks?
Instead of is_member() function in databricks, do we have any alternative function in python. If yes, what is the function name?